# Summary of Keras Model Class

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using TensorFlow and Keras in order to build a Deep Learning Model. Now I want to print a summary of it by using the model.summary method.
As my Model consists of multiple TensorFlow.keras.models.Model objects, I can only get a summary like that:

```
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                    
==================================================================================================
input_4 (InputLayer)                (None, 10000)        0       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
model1 (Functional)                (None, 15800)        141650      input_4[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
model2 (Functional)                (None, 3)            47403       model1[0][0]                       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
model3 (Functional)                (None, 4)            63204       model1[0][0]                        
==================================================================================================
```

I am constructing each of the three models within a method. Within this method, I can obtain a detailed summary of model1 through

```
model.summary()
```

However, I do not return this Sequential Object from the Method so this is no solution for me.
What I am returning is

```
input = Input(shape=(a,b,c))
latent = model(input)
return Model(input, latent, name='model1')
```

Is there any possibility to get a detailed summary of each of my models?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: model.layers[1].summary() to get the summary of model1

Comment: This only shows me a summary with one Sequential Layer, even though, the model has about 15 layers. Thanks anyway, as you have given me the right idea: model.layer[1].layers[1].summary() did the trick :-)